# How can I make a gameObject with Boxcollider2d and the Boxcollider2D effects to gameObject A but moving through gameObject B

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm new in unity and i'm trying to buid a 2d game and I want to know how to create a gameobject with boxcollider2d and the boxcollider2D just work when the game hits gameObject A but do not work when interacting to gameobject B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign your objects to [different Layers](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/LayerBasedCollision.html).

By doing this you can either set them to collide with each other, or to ignore any collisions between them. So make an A layer for all your A objects, and a B layer for all your B objects.  (Of course you can name it whatever you like) Go to

> Edit > Project Settings > Physics

where you can edit the layer collision matrix, to enable or disable collisions between layer elements.

[image]